# Any special meaning for "negative verb+なる (なってくる)"?

Tags: grammar

In the ヨコハマ買い出し紀行 manga (v.5 ch.32) there's a sentence

> また、南町にコーヒー豆が**入らなくなってきて**、今日は、うちも休日。

English translation reads

> I **need** to visit the south town for coffee beans again, but today is a day off at home.

Do I understand it correctly that the actual translation would be closer to

> And again I'm not going *(for some time already)* to Minamimachi for coffee beans, so today is a day off at home.

and that "**need**" is actually not in the sentence itself but is inferred: "I didn't go for some time" => "I have to go"?  Or does "negative verb+なってくる" indeed has the meaning/nuance of "have to"?

**Update:** perhaps "入らなくなってきて" here actually means "*it so happened that* I'm not going" - is it so?

Comment: I have no idea where in the original you see a "I'm not going" and Google Translate sees a "I need to visit".  Those are not said or implied AT ALL.

Comment: @l'électeur, that 's what the question was about, it helps to expand on what you actually *do* see.  I assume you agree with the answer below, but then, I assumed a wrong subject of the sentence, so I may be wrong again ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I don't think the English translation you report is totally correct.

I see 入る here as with the meaning of "get in", as in the sense of "arrive", "get in stock" since we're talking of coffee beans. The construction then is simply negative + なる(--> て-form) + てーくる. I believe that in this case simply てーくる indicates that a certain change (the beans not coming) has been taking place up to now.

Here some explanations about this grammatical structure in general:

http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/087.html

and in English:

http://maggiesensei.com/2010/03/13/requested-lesson-%E3%80%8C%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%8F%EF%BC%8B%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8Dteiku-tekuru/

So I would translate it roughly as:

*again, coffee beans weren't coming (had not arrived/were not arriving) to the south town, (hence) today I will also have a day off.*

I also think that うち here is used as to express oneself rather than the house as a physical object (but it might depend on the other context).

Anyway, I am not a native speaker so take it with a grain of salt, but I think what I said above is correct.

Comment: You did better than OP, but why "south town"?  Hint: There is a huge difference between 南町 and 南の町.

Comment: @Tommy, Perhaps you are right.  I suspected the subject may be beans because it's strange to say 町に入る about a person, but I somehow expected を in place of が then - probably incorrectly.

As for うち - probably "home" in this particular case since in the previous 4 volumes the main character always referred to herself as 私 (you couldn't know this of course).  But then, I'm yet to see if it has changed...

Comment: @l'électeur 読んだことない作品なので予想ですが、本作では既に日本という国自体が崩壊しています。[これ](http://uheei.yu-nagi.com/main_200.html)とか[これ](http://cafe-alpha.org/cafealpha/etc/meisyo.htm)を見る限り、作者はあまり実在の地名を出すのを好まず、設定面で読者に解釈を委ねる傾向にあるようです（主人公の住居も「西の岬」とだけ語られファンの間でも所在が確定していない）。ここで出ている「南町」も実在の行政区画名というより、本当にぼんやり「南の町」なんだろなという気がします。

Comment: @l'électeur I just translated that literally as given that there is no much context I couldn't guess more. Also, I did not put too much thought into it as that was not the main point of the question. You are right of course, there is a difference between 南町 and 南の町. But also, how many 南町 there are?

https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8D%97%E7%94%BA

Edit: I was suddenly called in a meeting while replying so I missed the above comments before refreshing the page.

Comment: @kroki Ok, well as I said I had no much context. About the が、 I think it is because 入る is 自動詞: http://web.ydu.edu.tw/~uchiyama/1h93fy/jita.html

Answer (score 2):

You've already gotten a lot of comments pointing you in the right direction, but why not also a more idiomatic translation; mind, this is without context, but I'm imagining some war / disaster / post apocalyptic situation.

また、南町にコーヒー豆が入{はい}らなくなってきて、今日は、うちも休日。
With the supply of coffee beans again run dry in Minami-chou, looks like today's gonna be a day off (for me / us / my store / our store) too.

Again no beans have come into the city area, so this person, today at least, is also forced to not do business (perhaps he runs a cafe?) in addition to other stores which are also closed.

The translation takes a little liberty making the original closer to 今日は、（仕方なく）うち（の店）も休日（にするしかないみたい）

Comment: I, as a reader of this comic, think this answer is most correct. The heroine is taking care of a drive-by cafe off 南町 (I guess it's みなみまち) in a world after disastrous sea level rising and the humanity slowly declines. When supply falls short, she has to take a long ride to Yokohama (btw Tokyo is already sunk) to buy them. Thus the title ヨコハマ買い出し紀行.

Comment: I accepted the other answer for its many links, but you convinced me that うち is indeed for うちの店 in this context.  Thanks!